# How can I add style on map having type:multilinestring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

```
addfeatures(data) {
  let map = this.map;
  var testing = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: []
  };
  testing.features.push({
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": JSON.parse(data)
  });
  featureLayer = new google.maps.Data();
  this.clearOverlay();
  featureLayer.addGeoJson(testing);
  featureLayer.setStyle({
    fillColor: 'purple',
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  featureLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

here data having result like:

```
{
  "type":"MultiLineString",
  "coordinates":[[
    [-13063926.5701,4084309.8696],
    [-13063917.2422,4084309.8973]
  ]]
}
```

so how to add style for this? it not displaying on map.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to append a jsFiddle (or other) when you have problem with map or something graphic. Otherwise, you're limited answers to people that exactly know your problem.

Comment: i have one button when click on button it call the function map.addfeature(data) so var data = {"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-13063926.5701,4084309.8696],[-13063917.2422,4084309.8973]]]};

Comment: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" getting error json

Comment: Is your `data` already a JS object (not a JSON string)?

Comment: when i use JSON.parse(data) so in console log it shows Object{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-13063926.5701,40‌​84309.8696],[-130639‌​17.2422,4084309.8973‌​]]]}

Comment: here i use setMap to set the style but it not displaying on map

Comment: What kind of styles you want to add for `Map` if your `data.type` is `MultiLineString` ?

Comment: I want to add style fillcolor:'blue' using setStyle